# How do I return the deleted file, which name I do not know?

Tags: git, github

I want to **recover** **my deleted** file, which is unfortunately deleted but it was *important* for me and also I just forgot this **file name**. under the circumstances what can do it for?

Comment: How was it deleted?  Was it already under source control by Git?  What have you done?  What have you tried?

Comment: it was deleted Unintentionally. At that time git was not installed on this file.i tried to recover but i don't know what command will help to bring this file

Comment: If it was not a part of git why is this question tagged git? Which operating system and file system are you using? You would need a recovery tool, which depends on the file system.

Comment: i am using windows 10.

Comment: if you know this please tell me

Comment: Did you check in recycle bean?

Comment: recycle bean is clean. that's why i facing a problem

Answer (score 0):

If the file had not yet been added to Git, and it's no longer in the Recycle Bin, all I can recommend is a Google search for "recover deleted files on Windows 10".